# Panda DataFrame get value from column based on condition in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and have tried various ways to code. Here is the dataframe:

```
   Geofence              Time_in             Time_out Total_time
0      30TA  2022-07-12 20:34:07  2022-07-12 20:44:36    0:10:29
1       KNS  2022-07-12 20:47:08  2022-07-12 20:51:39    0:04:31
2       KNS  2022-07-12 20:52:09  2022-07-12 20:54:37    0:02:28
3       KNS  2022-07-12 21:04:38  2022-07-12 21:24:40    0:20:02
4      30TA  2022-07-12 21:27:13  2022-07-12 21:33:13    0:06:00
5       KNS  2022-07-12 21:37:14  2022-07-12 22:00:16    0:23:02
6      30TA  2022-07-12 22:02:44  2022-07-12 22:19:48    0:17:04
7       KNS  2022-07-12 22:22:19  2022-07-12 22:44:49    0:22:30
8      30TA  2022-07-12 22:46:49  2022-07-12 22:48:49    0:02:00
9      30TA  2022-07-12 22:50:22  2022-07-12 22:55:52    0:05:30
10     30TA  2022-07-12 22:56:23  2022-07-12 23:11:24    0:15:01
11      KNS  2022-07-12 23:13:54  2022-07-12 23:39:27    0:25:33
12     30TA  2022-07-12 23:41:27  2022-07-12 23:47:27    0:06:00
```

We wish to get

```
'Geofence': 30TA, 'Time in': 2022-07-12 20:34:07 and 'Time out': 2022-07-12 20:44:36
'Geofence': KNS, 'Time in': 2022-07-12 20:47:08 and 'Time out': 2022-07-12 21:24:40
'Geofence': 30TA, 'Time in': 2022-07-12 21:27:13 and 'Time out': 2022-07-12 21:33:13
```

Issue: problem encountered when there are multiple rows ('Geofence': KNS and further down 'Geofence': 30TA). We wish to get 'Time in' of 1st occurrence of 'KNS' and 'Time out' of 3rd occurrence of 'KNS'

In other words, time in the geofence needs to be summarized by fence-time group.  In the example data the first fence-time group is row 0.  The next fence-time group is represented in rows 1-3.  Then next is row 4.  For each fence-time group the output should include the geofence name, the time first entered the fence and the time exiting the fence.  These are represented by the first `Time in` and the last `Time out`.  This shows the relation between fence time groups and the output:

[image]

The output can be a dataframe with `Geofence`, `Time in` and `time out` columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'KNS_Night_Shift_GPS_Report_2022-07-15.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df = df.loc[df['Grouping'] == 'XE3257X', ['Geofence', 'Time in', 'Time out']]

for i, g in df.groupby(['Geofence']):
    print(g)
```

Comment: Hi yes precisely. The updated diagram clearly indicates the desired output. Thank you

Comment: I edited this question in order to get it re-opened.  The reason I did that is that I have an answer for you.

Comment: In fact - what follows is the answer.  You will have to fix the formatting since a comment strips line feeds out.

Comment: `def fence_grouper(x): return pd.Series([x['Geofence'].iloc[0], x['Time in'].min(), x['Time out'].max()])`

Comment: `dfg = ( df.assign(grp=(df['Geofence'] != df['Geofence'].shift()).cumsum()).groupby('grp').apply(fence_grouper).set_axis(['Geofence','Time in','Time out'], axis=1, inplace=False).reset_index(drop=True) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Define where a change happens, so we can make a new group for each:
groupme = (df.Geofence
             .ne(df.Geofence.shift() # Not equal to the previous value.
                   .fillna(df.Geofence)) # Added to include the first value
             .cumsum()) # Make the groups

out = (df.groupby(groupme, as_index=False)
         .agg({'Geofence': 'first', # Take the Geofence of the group.
               'Time_in':'min',     # Minimum of Time_in of the group.
               'Time_out':'max'}))  # Maximium of Time_out of the group.

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  Geofence              Time_in             Time_out
0     30TA  2022-07-12 20:34:07  2022-07-12 20:44:36
1      KNS  2022-07-12 20:47:08  2022-07-12 21:24:40
2     30TA  2022-07-12 21:27:13  2022-07-12 21:33:13
3      KNS  2022-07-12 21:37:14  2022-07-12 22:00:16
4     30TA  2022-07-12 22:02:44  2022-07-12 22:19:48
5      KNS  2022-07-12 22:22:19  2022-07-12 22:44:49
6     30TA  2022-07-12 22:46:49  2022-07-12 23:11:24
7      KNS  2022-07-12 23:13:54  2022-07-12 23:39:27
8     30TA  2022-07-12 23:41:27  2022-07-12 23:47:27
```